# Displaying random line from text file in text box code error

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a program that on a button click displays a random line from a text file into a text box.

I am only a beginner at C# so I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:...\QUESTIONS.text").Length;
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int randomLineNum = rnd.Next(lineCount);
   int indicator = 0;
   using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"D:...\QUESTIONS.text"))
   {
       while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
       {
           if (indicator == randomLineNum)
           {
               questionBox.Text = reader;
               break;
           }
           indicator++;
       }
   }
}
```

Can you also help me figure out where this code is supposed to go.

Thank you for your help in advance! : )

Comment: "Doesn't work" as in produces an error or absolutely nothing appears to happen? Have you set a breakpoint and tried to debug?

Comment: Nothing happened at all, but thanks to some cool guys it's all fixed now

Answer (score 2):

you can remove many complexities in your code.

```
private Random r = new Random();

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:...\QUESTIONS.text");
    questionBox.Text = lines[r.Next(lines.Length)];
}
```

1. defining a random variable outside the function scope and reuse it
   every time is a known best practice.
2. why reading the file twice? you are reading it once with `ReadAllLines` and then again with an `StreamReader`

Comment: ahhh.. I see.. Thank you. I will try to remember this in future

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:...\QUESTIONS.text");
    int lineCount = lines.Length;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomLineNum = rnd.Next(lineCount);
    questionBox.Text = lines[randomLineNum];
}
```

There is no need to read the same file twice, so keep the lines in a local variable to access it later.